# [AnyObject]?' does not have a member named 'Generator'

Tags: swift, for-loop, option-type

```
func retrieveMessages() {

    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Message")

    //Call findobjectsinbackground

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        self.messagesArray = [String]()
        for messageObject in objects {   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< error
            let messageText:String? = (messageObject as PFObject)["Text"] as? String
            if messageText != nil {
                self.messagesArray.append(messageText!)
            }
        }
        self.messageTableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

From this code an error occurs saying: `[AnyObject]? does not have a member named 'Generator'`. Is there a way how to correct this?

Comment: Please format your code correctly.

Comment: @returntrue The edit is already in the queue waiting to be approved.

Comment: @Pondpoud Has any of the answers helped you? If so, could you accept the one that has? Otherwise do you need anymore help?

Answer (score 11):

Your `objects` array is declared as an Optional : `objects:[AnyObject]?`

So you need to *unwrap* it before looping over it:

```
for messageObject in objects! {
    // do stuff
}
```

And since `objects` can be nil, better do this:

```
if let myObjects = objects {
    for messageObject in myObjects {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

Comment: Guys this is working,  awesome, I was stuck in this error for two hours. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

That's because it is an optional array. Simply wrap it around `if let` and you'll be fine.

*In playground:*

```
func retrieveMessages(objects:[AnyObject]?) {
    var messagesArray = [String]()

    if let objs = objects {
        for messageObject in objs {
            let messageText:String? = "test"
            if messageText != nil {
                messagesArray.append(messageText!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

*In your case*, the complete code would be:

```
func retrieveMessages() {
    var query:PFQuery = PFQuery(className: "Message")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects:[AnyObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        self.messagesArray = [String]()

        if let objs = objects {
            for messageObject in objs {
                let messageText:String? = (messageObject as PFObject)["Text"] as? String
                if messageText != nil {
                    self.messagesArray.append(messageText!)
                }
            }
        }

        self.messageTableView.reloadData() 
    } 
}
```

Comment: No problem, just make sure to mark it as an answer that you used. To make sure it doesn't appear as unanswered :-)

Answer (score 1):

Since your objects Array is of [AnyObject]?, before using them you need to do below step.

```
if let myObjects = objects as? [PFObject] {
   //Do the things...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[AnyObject]? it´s an optional array.

You must unwrap it before using it.

```
if let objects = objects
{
  for messageObject in objects 
  {
   ....
  }
}
```